# Taxi dispatcher on Purim

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I've heard that the role of taxi dispatcher (מְשַׁלֵּחַ מוֹנִיּוֹת) is an important one on Purim, but I don't have details.

1. Why is a taxi dispatcher so important on Purim?
2. What special role does the taxi dispatcher play on Purim?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Halachically it only reaches its full importance if Purim falls out on Shabbat and one has to travel in a Car-melit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The מְשַׁלֵּחַ מוֹנִיּוֹת is an extremely important character in the *megilla* story itself. However, as is the practice of the *megilla* the most important characters are not named specifically. If you pay close enough attention to the words, though, it's completely clear what's going on.

Of course, in the times of the *megilla*, the taxi dispatcher wasn't in charge of a bunch of cars... Such things didn't exist. When you needed to travel, you rode a horse and the taxis of the time were horses for rent. Now, the taxi dispatcher was a friend of the Jews. That's why when Achashverosh originally sent out his decree to kill all the Jews, the taxi dispatcher refused to send the horses out carrying such an evil decree. The messages had to be taken on foot:

> הָרָצִים יָצְאוּ דְחוּפִים
>
> The runners went out in haste
>
> <sup>[Esther 3:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3303.htm#15)</sup>

On the other hand, when Achashverosh realized what an evil man Haman was, he sent out another message allowing the Jews to defend themselves and in this case, the taxi dispatcher was happy to send out the horses:

> וַיִּשְׁלַח סְפָרִים בְּיַד הָרָצִים בַּסּוּסִים רֹכְבֵי הָרֶכֶשׁ, הָאֲחַשְׁתְּרָנִים--בְּנֵי, הָרַמָּכִים
>
> and sent letters by posts on horseback, riding on swift steeds that were used in the king's service, bred of the stud
>
> <sup>[Esther 8:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3308.htm#10)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

My answer may be a bit "localized", so take this within its context.

In a number of major cities in U.S., there is a cab comapny called "Uber". You have to download the Uber app to your smartphone, and you order the cab via your app. The point is, there is no cab dispatcher for Uber.

If you read the Megillah carefully, there is a discouragement to use Uber on Purim, as we see in Esther 9:27:

קימו וקבלו היהודים עליהם .... ולא י**עבר**

They accepted this upon them and not (to use) Uber

Well, if they can't use Uber on Purim, then they have to use a cab that has been dispatched to them. Hence, the need for the dispatcher.

Comment: Uber is all over the world. Not just the US

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. I wasn't sure. B"N, next time I'm in Canada, I'll ask for Ubereh?

Comment: What about Lyft? Or Curb?

Comment: @DonielF I wouldn't know. The verse that I cited, is specific to Uber.

Answer (score 4):

I think the important role he plays is keeping drunk drivers off the street. And even though this is accomplished mainly through the drivers, the dispatcher sent them, and shliach shel adam kimoso, when one sends an agent it is considered as if he did it himself.

Comment: I think you mean Shlucho Shel Adam KeMotor, sending a messenger is like being a vehicle itself.

Comment: That has the making for its own purim question. Or maybe why a messenger of a person is like his death?